# Quarkus Cucumber - Execution of multiple tests not possible

Tags: cucumber, quarkus

I'm using the [Quarkus Cucumber extension](https://quarkiverse.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-cucumber/dev/index.html) in version 1.0.0. I've added two tests with different steps, scenarios, etc.. Both test classes are extending from `CucumberQuarkusTest`.

Everything is running fine when only one test class is executed.

But when two `CucumberQuarkusTest` test classes are executed (e.g. via Intellij -> Run Test) only the first test is executed. The second one is already in "Terminated" state without running any tests. There's no exception visible on console.

The same behavior is when some other `@QuarkusTest` annotated tests are executed together with a `CucumberQuarkusTest`. All tests before the `CucumberQuarkusTest` are executed fine, the `CucumberQuarkusTest` itself is also executed fine. But tests after that `CucumberQuarkusTest` are again directly in terminated state without any error message.

When executing all tests running `mvn clean install` (test execution is configured with surefire-plugin) then all tests are executed without problems.

Does anybody know this strange behavior and can provide a solution?